# CSS: Pseudo-elements

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

The below CSS code puts the "*" after the list ends in a span element. See text below the code. I need to put the asterisk next to "Option 3" or after "TEXT SAMPLE:" line and NOT below it.

```
.asterisks:after
{
    color: Red;
    content: " *";
}
```

TEXT SAMPLE:

5. Test Question

a. Option 1

b. Option 2

c. Option 3

*

I'm using the "asterisk" class for 100 elements in my project and it works well but fails only when it comes to list.

Also, this list is coming from XML document and Not aspx.

Any suggestions please?

Comment: Can you share the HTML of your text sample?

Comment: `<asp:Label ID="QuestionText" runat="server" CssClass="asterisk">    </asp:Label>`

That's pretty much and the values are coming from XML.

Comment: What about the XML then? I'm trying to see exactly what schema you're trying to match the CSS against.

Comment: `<DisplayText>5. <![CDATA[Test Text Test:<ul><li>Option 1</li><li>Option 2</li><li>Option 3</li></ul>]]></DisplayText>`

Comment: The last-child answer is the right selector from the answer below

Comment: Please give your question a more descriptive title.

Comment: Put all the relevant code *in the question itself* by editing it, not writing it in comments.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the last-child selector:

**html**

```
<ul class="asterisks">
    <li>option 1</li>
    <li>option 2</li>
    <li>option 3</li>
</ul>
```

**css**

```
.asterisks li:last-child:after
{
    color: Red;
    content: " *";
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9m7yh1cd/1/

Comment: As I presume this will be used to mark the correct answer or something similar, I think using `nth-of-type` would be more appropriate because the number is likely to change